# There's a Hole in my ViewBag Dear Liza

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, viewbag

I have the following simple view that is used to send invitations out to register for our web-site. This is in an admin-only view and once the email address is filled out the admin can click and send the invite. The code is

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Tools", FormMethod.Post,
        new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <h2>Invite Users</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmailAddress, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress, 
                    new { @class = "form-control", id = "email" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Access To", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Product", new SelectList(
                    new List<Object> {
                        new { Text = "D", Value = "D" },
                        new { Text = "U", Value = "U" },
                        new { Text = "All", Value = "All" }},
                        "Value",
                        "Text"),
                        new { @class = "form-control", id = "product" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <span class="label label-danger">@ViewBag.FailedMessage</span>
                <span class="label label-success">@ViewBag.SuccessMessage</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="button" value="Invite User" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

To post back to the controller on the button click with the selected combo-box selection, I use the following Java Script

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("input[type=button]").click(function () {
            var data_email = $('#email').val();
            var data_product = $('#product option:selected').text();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Tools/SendInvite',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { email: data_email, product: data_product },
                success: function (result) {
                }
            });
        });
    });
 </script>
```

The controller method for this is

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> SendInvite(
    string email, string product)
{
    ApplicationUser user = null;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (user.IsAdmin != null && (bool)user.IsAdmin)
        {
            string key = String.Empty;
            string subMsg = String.Empty;
            var accessDB = new AccessHashesDbContext();
            switch (product) { /* do stuff */ }

            // Send email.
            try
            {
                await Helpers.SendEmailAsync(new List<string>() { email }, null, "my message string");
                ViewBag.FailedMessage = String.Empty;
                ViewBag.SuccessMessage = String.Format(
                    "Invitation successfully sent to \"{0}\"",
                    email);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ViewBag.SuccessMessage = String.Empty;
                ViewBag.FailedMessage = String.Format(
                    "Invitation to \"{0}\" failed",
                    email);
            }
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

This code works and sends my email template off to the required recipient. However, I want to notify that the email has been sent or has failed to send via the `ViewBag`. This code seems to work, but in the view the `ViewBag` is empty and no messages are displayed, **what am I doing wrong here?**

Thanks for your time.

---

*Edit. by using @yhax's answer below, I have come to the following attempted solution; in my controller I have*

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> SendInvite(string email, string product)
{
    ApplicationUser user = null;
    string result = "{\"invite_result\":\"{0}\",\"invite_success\":\"{1}\"}";
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (user.IsAdmin != null && (bool)user.IsAdmin)
        {
            string key = String.Empty;
            string subMsg = String.Empty;
            var accessDB = new AccessHashesDbContext();
            switch (product) { /* do stuff */ }

            // Send email.
            try
            {
                await Helpers.SendEmailAsync(new List<string>() { email }, null, "my message string");
                result = String.Format(result, 
                    String.Format("Invitation successfully sent to \"{0}\"", email), 
                    "true");
                return Content(result);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                result = String.Format(result, 
                    String.Format("Invitation to \"{0}\" failed", email), 
                    "false");
                return Content(result);
            }
        }
    }
    result = String.Format(result, "Invite Failed", "false");
    return Content(result);
}
```

*In my JavaScript within my view I now have:*

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("input[type=button]").click(function () {
            var data_email = $('#email').val();
            var data_product = $('#product option:selected').text();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Tools/SendInvite',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { email: data_email, product: data_product },
                success: function (result) {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(jsontext);
                    if (obj.invite_success == "true") {
                        $('#fail_message').val("");
                        $('#success_message').val(obj.invite_result);
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#fail_message').val(obj.invite_result);
                        $('#success_message').val("");
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Invite Failure");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

*This is always hitting the `error` condition and shows an alert. When I comment this `error: function()` out, then my post does not fire to the controller! What am I doing wrong in this case?*

Comment: You're returning the `View` but you do nothing with the result in JS

Comment: Your checking Viewback when the page initlay loads. Viewbag wont be checked again until the page refreshes. I would return an obj from your SendInvite email, then in your ajax success, check that obj for your conditions.

Comment: Rather than returning `View()` and using `ViewBag`, return `Json(new { Message = "Some messge"});`

Comment: Oh, so the `ViewBag` is only check when the initial load happens! @BenRobinson how would I access the Json object from the view?

Comment: It would be a property on the `result` parameter passed to your success callback in you JavaScript. Probably `result.data.Message` or similar, you should debug to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> SendInvite(
    string email, string product)
{
    ApplicationUser user = null;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (user.IsAdmin != null && (bool)user.IsAdmin)
        {
            string key = String.Empty;
            string subMsg = String.Empty;
            var accessDB = new AccessHashesDbContext();
            switch (product) { /* do stuff */ }

            // Send email.
            try
            {
                await Helpers.SendEmailAsync(new List<string>() { email }, null, "my message string");
                return Content(String.Format("Invitation successfully sent to \"{0}\"", email));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Content(String.Format(
                    "Invitation to \"{0}\" failed",
                    email));
            }
        }
    }
// you could redirect to another action, or return some other message
    return Content("not valid etc etc");
}
```

and then in here you could do something with the returned message:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("input[type=button]").click(function () {
            var data_email = $('#email').val();
            var data_product = $('#product option:selected').text();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Tools/SendInvite',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { email: data_email, product: data_product },
                success: function (result) {
// do something here... show a box with the message, whatever you like
console.log(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank very much for this. I am a total noob to this stuff. I know how to get data from HTML elements, but how would I set properties (like my `label`) from the JavaScript? Any additional information or link on this would be massively appreciated...

Comment: All you would need to do is make sure your HTML elements have id's set on them. For example <a id="bla"...  you can also set the property as your are already doing in the razor code. Then using jQuery you could target those fields and do whatever you like $("#bla").someJqueryFunction. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193916/how-to-set-textbox-value-in-jquery  - they don't have to have id's, you could do this other ways as well, but if you can set the unique id, it would be easiest.

Comment: One final thing, I would like to have two label colours depending on the result. With the code above you only pass back one string object. How would I pass back two string objects, one for each label?

Comment: Take a look at this, it has everything you need - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227624/asp-net-mvc-controller-actions-that-return-json-or-partial-html