# how to get values inside a particular textbox using jquery and store it into a variable using onfocus

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a textbox as shown below,

```
<input type="text" name="company" id="company" required />
```

My question is, I want to get the values inside the textbox using jquery whenever I typed or selected the values.

I have tried a lot but no effect. The jquery i have tried is below,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var input = $('#company').val();
    $("#tag").autocomplete("autocomplete1.php?str="+input, {
        selectFirst: true
    });
});
```

The above code has no effect. Is there any method. Kindly help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show full code or make a Fiddle.

Comment: you will check your answer on this link :

[how to set textbox value in jquery][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193916/how-to-set-textbox-value-in-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind Jquery event on change like,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#company').focus(function(){
        var input = $('#company').val();
        $("#tag").autocomplete("autocomplete1.php?str="+input, {
            selectFirst: true
        });
    });
});
```

There are many other events you can bind, [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/) is the official documentation of Jquery for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

http://jsfiddle.net/whxbLos4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#company').on('change : focus : keypress', function() { 
        //  this.value is what you need       
        $('#result').html(this.value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `on` `blur` to get it on `focusout` as an alternative as below:

```
$('#company').on('blur',function(){
      var input = $(this).val();
      //Other codes
});
```